# How do I test whether a variable has multiple non-blank lines in bash?

Tags: bash

Say I have two variables in bash:

```
MULTILINE="I have
more than one line"
SINGLE_LINE="I only have one line
"
```

I want to detect when a variable actually contains more than one line of text, disregarding extra trailing newline characters.

So this:

```
if [ some test on "$MULTILINE" ]; then echo 'yes'; else echo 'no'; fi
```

would print `yes`, and this:

```
if [ some test on "$SINGLE_LINE" ]; then echo 'yes'; else echo 'no'; fi
```

would print `no`.

For my specific case, I don't think I need to worry about leading blank lines, but it wouldn't hurt to know how to do that.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/bash-test-for-newline

Comment: @krowe Thank you, but can you point to an specific answers there that ignore trailing blank lines? I didn't see any. (Also edited the title accordingly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution I know is:

```
if (( $(grep -c . <<<"$MULTILINE") > 1 ))
```

eg:

```
VAR="a
b"
if (( $(grep -c . <<<"$VAR") > 1 )); then
  echo VAR has more than one line
else
  echo VAR has at most one line
fi
```

==>

```
VAR has more than one line
```

The above ignores all blank lines: leading, trailing and interior. But note that it is not possible to have an interior blank line unless there are at least two non-blank lines, so its existence cannot alter the question of whether there are more than one line after trimming leading and trailing blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ echo "$MULTILINE" | wc -l
2

$ echo "$SINGLE_LINE" | wc -l
2

$ echo "$SINGLE_LINE" | sed -re '/^$/d' | wc -l
1

$ echo "$MULTILINE" | sed -re '/^$/d' | wc -l
2
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed
for more on how to trim/delete whitespace and empty lines using sed.

Now to write your `if expression ...` use  `$( ... )` inside quotes to get the number of lines, and test against the number:

```
if [ "$(echo "$MULTILINE" | sed -re '/^$/d' | wc -l)" -gt 1 ]; then 
  echo 'more than one line'; 
else 
  echo 'single or no line'; 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to [this code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/bash-test-for-newline) should do it. You can put it in it's own script for reuse like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nlhit=""
for (( i=0; i<${#1}; i++ )); do
    if [[ "${1:$i:1}" == $'\n' ]]; then
        nlhit="1"
    elif [[ "$nlhit" == "1" ]]; then
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Then you can use it like so (assuming that you named the previous script `multiline-check.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

EMPTYLINE=""
BLANKLINE="    "
ONLYLINES="


"

MULTILINE="I have
more than one line"
SINGLE_LINE="I only have one line
"
SECOND_LINE="
I begin with a newline"


echo -n "EMPTYLINE Check: "
multiline-check.sh "$EMPTYLINE"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi

echo -n "BLANKLINE Check: "
multiline-check.sh "$BLANKLINE"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi

echo -n "ONLYLINES Check: "
multiline-check.sh "$ONLYLINES"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi

echo -n "MULTILINE Check: "
multiline-check.sh "$MULTILINE"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi

echo -n "SINGLE_LINE Check: "
multiline-check.sh "$SINGLE_LINE"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi

echo -n "SECOND_LINE Check: "
multiline-check.sh "$SECOND_LINE"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the first `fi`. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on bash 3.1 (msysgit version). I don't see anything that looks like a syntax error to me, but obviously I'm missing something. Thoughts?

Comment: @jpmc26 It did have an error. I've updated it to be an external script so that it is easier to use as well.

Comment: @jpmc26 I've added some more checks to test other odd input.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ignoring trailing blank lines

Here is an approach using `awk`:

```
echo "$TEST" | tac | awk 'f==0 && /./ {f=NR} END{if(f==NR){exit 0}; exit 1 }' && echo "Found A Single Line"
```

How it works:

- echo "$TEST"

  This takes whatever shell variable we are interested in and sends it to standard out.
- `tac`

  This reverses the order of the lines so that the last line is returned first.  After executing `tac`, the trailing lines become the leading lines.

  (The name `tac` is the reverse of `cat` for the reason that `tac` does what `cat` does but in reverse.)
- `awk 'f==0 && /./ {f=NR} END{if(f==NR){exit 0}; exit 1 }'`

  This stores the line number of the first non-blank line in the variable `f`.  After reading in all the lines, it compares `f` to the total number of lines, `NR`.  if `f` is equal to `NR`, then we had just a single line (ignoring initial blanks) and we exit with code 0.  If there were one or more lines after the first blank line, then it exits with code `.
- `&& echo "Found A Single Line"`

  If `awk` exited with code 0, then the `echo` statement is executed.

#### Ignoring both leading and trailing blank lines

By creating one additional `awk` variable, we can extend the test to ignore both leading and trailing blank lines:

```
echo "$TEST" | awk 'first==0 && /./ {first=NR} /./ {last=NR} END{if(first==last){exit 0}; exit 1 }' && echo " Found A Single Line"
```

Because this version of the `awk` code handles both leading and trailing blanks, `tac` is no longer needed.

Taking the `awk` code a piece at a time:

- `first==0 && /./ {first=NR}`

  If the variable `first` is zero (or it hasn't been set yet) and the line has a character, any character, then set `first` to the line number.  When `awk` is done reading the lines, `first` will be set to the line number of the first non-blank line.
- `/./ {last=NR}`

  If the line has any character in it, then set the variable `last` to the current line number.  When `awk` is done reading all the lines, this variable will has the line number of the last non-blank line.
- `END{if(first==last){exit 0}; exit 1 }`

  This executed after all the lines have been read.  If `first` is equal to `last`, then we have seen zero or line non-blank lines and `awk` exits with code `0`.  Otherwise, it exits with code `1`.  The shell script can test the exit code as usual with `if` statements or `&&` or `||`.